apt.daily.timer override file doesn't seem to work
I already successfully modified the schedule of the unattended upgrades by modifying /lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer and /lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer directly. This works so far as I can see in the /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log.
Meanwhile I've learned those files could be overwritten by a package update and the better way would be to use override files like /etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer and /etc/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer.
So I did the following:

copied the originals from /lib/[...] to /etc/systemd/system/ and modified them by sudo systemctl edit --full apt-daily.timer

Then I did systemctl daemon-reload

double checked:

/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer still shows the default times

/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer shows my modified times

systemctl status apt-daily.timer | grep loaded gives me the following what looks fine in my eyes:
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)



Now I checked the /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log and felt disappointed :) because it didn't show any activities at the expected time range.
[edit] Here the requested output and the (for test purposes) updated timer-files:

systemctl list-timers apt-daily.timer

NEXT                         LEFT          LAST                         PASSED UNIT            ACTIVATES
Tue 2024-07-30 08:50:33 CEST 4min 12s left Tue 2024-07-30 00:51:56 CEST 7h ago apt-daily.timer apt-daily.service
1 timers listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive timers, too.


systemctl list-timers apt-daily-upgrade.timer

NEXT                         LEFT      LAST                         PASSED       UNIT                    ACTIVATES
Tue 2024-07-30 08:53:33 CEST 7min left Tue 2024-07-30 06:35:34 CEST 2h 10min ago apt-daily-upgrade.timer apt-daily-upgrade.service
1 timers listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive timers, too.

Did I oversee / miss anything?
My upgrade override files (times changed for test purpose):
cat /etc/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer
[Unit]
Description=Daily apt download activities

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 8:50
RandomizedDelaySec=1m
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target

cat /etc/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer
[Unit]
Description=Daily apt upgrade and clean activities
After=apt-daily.timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 8:53
RandomizedDelaySec=1m
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target

OS release:
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"

Final thought for now: Maybe the randomized delay of 1m is too small to be processed? So I changed the override-files to 09:20 and 09:28 with 5m delay each. Will keep you updated.
Update 31.07.2024:
Based on what I described as "Final thought" above I found that now the override files seem to be working:

As you can see in the following log yesterday (2024-07-31) the unattended upgrade script was started at 06:36 what seems to fit to the default timer setting files in /lib/systemd/system.
But today (2024-07-31) it was started at 09:21 for update and 09:30 for upgrade - what's perfectly hitting my most recent settings in the override-files as described above in the "Final thought":

tail -n 100 /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log
[...]
2024-07-30 06:36:05,251 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2024-07-30 06:36:05,252 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-infra-security
2024-07-30 06:36:05,252 INFO Initial blacklist:
2024-07-30 06:36:05,252 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict):
2024-07-30 06:36:06,204 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
2024-07-31 09:21:56,021 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2024-07-31 09:21:56,021 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-infra-security
2024-07-31 09:21:56,021 INFO Initial blacklist:
2024-07-31 09:21:56,021 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict):
2024-07-31 09:30:17,166 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2024-07-31 09:30:17,166 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-infra-security
2024-07-31 09:30:17,166 INFO Initial blacklist:
2024-07-31 09:30:17,166 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict):
2024-07-31 09:30:20,709 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: libpython3.10 libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless python3.10 python3.10-minimal
2024-07-31 09:30:20,709 INFO Writing dpkg log to /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log
2024-07-31 09:32:16,529 INFO All upgrades installed

However: To be complete here the ls -lah /var/lib/apt/periodic/
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul  5  2023 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4.0K Jul 31 09:31 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 31 09:22 download-upgradeable-stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 31 09:32 unattended-upgrades-stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 31 09:21 update-stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 31 09:21 update-success-stamp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Jul 31 09:32 upgrade-stamp

I cannot double check this by further research or test today but based on this symptoms it seems that a very short randomization like "1m" is just invalid. (Seems legit but I didn't expect it at this point.)
**

Do you agree?
Did you see something similar anytime before?
**

Thanks a lot for your support and your time!

Please edit your question to show the complete output, properly formatted, of systemctl list-timers apt-daily.timer. It's wide output, so be sure to copy it all.

It is also a good idea to always include the version of Ubuntu you are using in any question.

Hi @user535733, thanks for your reply. I updated the post meanwhile. Hopefully the added information bring a little light. :)

Hi @DavidDE, Thanks for your reply, too, and sorry for missing basic information first. Added it meanwhile. We're talking about Ubuntu 22.04.

Your output shows that your timers are set to exactly what you wanted: 08:50 and 08:53. Next, please edit your question to show us /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log output showing an entire 24-hour day demonstrating no action at the desired time while those timers are active. Also please show us the complete output of ls -lah /var/lib/apt/periodic/

Hi @user535733, thanks for your input. I added the requested information. Further it seems to work now. Please find the details added to the post.

Dear @user535733 and DavidDE
Thanks for your time and help! I just double checked the unattended-upgrades.log and it runs in the planned time range since I extended the "RandomizedDelaySec" to "5m". For production needs I will extend it a little more of course.
Didn't find an explanation like this so far but it seems to be stable, so I add this as "answer".
Thanks again!
